Adding Inner Separators to a Tikzpicture with Tikzpagenodes
Consider the code:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin=0in,vmargin=0in,right=0in,paperwidth=4.00in,paperheight=2.15in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfornament, tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usepackage{color}
%\definecolor{gold}{RGB}{215,190,105}

\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=myborder, color=transparent!0, inner sep=0.4cm]
    \node[below right] at (current page text area.north west) {\pgfornament[width=2cm]{63}};
    \node[below left ] at (current page text area.north east) {\pgfornament[width=2cm, symmetry=v]{63}};
    \node[above right] at (current page text area.south west) {\pgfornament[width=2cm, symmetry=h]{63}};
    \node[above left ] at (current page text area.south east) {\pgfornament[width=2cm, symmetry=c]{63}};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}

\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=mytext, color=transparent!0]
    \node (n) at (current page text area) {\scalebox{1.00}{}};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}


\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
        \fill[blue!35] (current page text area.south west) rectangle (current page text area.north east);
        \fill[path fading=myborder, fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, transform canvas={xshift=1pt, yshift=-1pt}] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
        \fill[path fading=myborder, fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, ball color=blue] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
        \fill[path fading=mytext  , fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, transform canvas={yshift=-1.35pt}]  (n.south west) rectangle (n.north east);
        \fill[path fading=mytext  , fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, ball color=blue] (n.south west) rectangle (n.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

which produces

In the code, inner sep=0.4cm (\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=myborder, color=transparent!0, inner sep=0.4cm])---
which adds a gap of 0.4cm all around the rectangle.
I would like to increase that gap another 0.4cm only at the top and bottom of the rectangle (not the sides). How may I do that? I could not find out what command will allow me to do that in the documentation for tikzpagenodes.
Thank you.

Did you try inner ysep?

and inner xsep, if required. might be a bit easier to read the code if you use inner ysep and inner xsep and will avoid any dependency on ordering of options.

@JasperHabict Thank you for your helpful comment. I could not get it to work (along with inner xcep= if I used inner sep=; however, if I take out inner sep= and replace it with the xsep and ysep specifications---everything seems to be fine. Thanks again.

@cfr Thank you. Combining your comment with the other, I got it to work.

@JasperHabicht do you want to answer?

@DDS I think you need to make sure that inner sep does not overwrite the inner xsep setting. I can post an answer later.

@JasperHabicht  Yes; I have removed inner sep when using the two others---xsep and ysep. Thanks.

You can just use inner ysep (there is also inner xsep which might be of some use as well). If you want to increase the vertical inner sep by another 0.4cm, just add inner ysep=0.8cm to the option list:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin=0in,vmargin=0in,right=0in,paperwidth=4.00in,paperheight=2.15in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfornament, tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usepackage{color}
%\definecolor{gold}{RGB}{215,190,105}

\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=myborder, color=transparent!0, inner sep=0.4cm, inner ysep=0.8cm]
    \node[below right] at (current page text area.north west) {\pgfornament[width=2cm]{63}};
    \node[below left ] at (current page text area.north east) {\pgfornament[width=2cm, symmetry=v]{63}};
    \node[above right] at (current page text area.south west) {\pgfornament[width=2cm, symmetry=h]{63}};
    \node[above left ] at (current page text area.south east) {\pgfornament[width=2cm, symmetry=c]{63}};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}

\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=mytext, color=transparent!0]
    \node (n) at (current page text area) {\scalebox{1.00}{}};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}


\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
        \fill[blue!35] (current page text area.south west) rectangle (current page text area.north east);
        \fill[path fading=myborder, fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, transform canvas={xshift=1pt, yshift=-1pt}] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
        \fill[path fading=myborder, fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, ball color=blue] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
        \fill[path fading=mytext  , fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, transform canvas={yshift=-1.35pt}]  (n.south west) rectangle (n.north east);
        \fill[path fading=mytext  , fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, ball color=blue] (n.south west) rectangle (n.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Many thanks for your helpful answer.

I understand that If I set inner xsep=0.4cm then there is a margin of 0.4cm on both the left and right hand sides. In the event that I wanted the left x-side set at 0.4cm but I also wanted the right x-side set at, say, 0.6cm---is there a way to do that? Thank you in advance.

@DDS For different margins on the right and the left refer to your other question. There is no simple way to do this with inner sep.
